# Is there a way to change the shape of answer options on google forms?

Tags: google-forms, google-forms-api

I'm making a survey and was wondering if there was a way to make the multiple choice answer options have a square box instead of circular? I don't mean for multiple answer options, I still want it to be multiple choice but the format needs to have a square around it. Is limiting the multiple answers option to just accept one my only option?
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The format of an option box is not a matter of formatting; it is a reflection of HTML standards, specifically the `input type`. This is not something that can be modified by CSS.